# Find duplicate string in 2d string array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, md5, duplicates

I've had a look through the previous posting and could not find one that answers this question. If possible, please could you point me at the right direction.

I am in the process of making a C# WPF file duplicate finder using MD5 and I am storing the file name and MD5 hash in a 2D array, this was the quickest way I thought I could implement this but I am having a problem with this.

The code below is of what I am trying to do:

```
public void fileList(string filename)
{
    string[,] fileLocationHash;
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(filename, "*.*", 
      SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        FileStream file = new FileStream(files[i], FileMode.Open);
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(file);
        file.Close();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int x = 0; x < retVal.Length; x++)
        {
            sb.Append(retVal[x].ToString("x2"));
        }
        string fileHash = sb.ToString();
        // 2D array to compare hash and find duplicates
        fileLocationHash = new string[,]
        {
            {files[i], fileHash}
        };
        resultTextbox.Text = resultTextbox.Text
          .Insert(resultTextbox.CaretIndex, fileHash + Environment.NewLine);
        resultTextbox.Text = resultTextbox.Text
          .Insert(resultTextbox.CaretIndex, files[i] + " - ");
    }
}
```

I am having problems implementing a for loop to go through the fileHash section of the 2D array and finding duplicates. I cant seen to be able to figure out how to choose the 2nd part of the array, as I assumed that the following would work:

```
 var duplicates = fileLocationHash[]
         .GroupBy(g => g).Where(w => w.Count() > 1).Select(s => s.Key);
 foreach (var d in duplicates);
```

But this shows an error with `fileLocationHash[]` and I can't seem to understand how I would keep and index of the found files, which I will need to have in order to print out the name of the file from the other section of the 2D array.

Comment: Side note: Please use custom class or even `KeyValuePair<string,string>` to make your code more readable...

Comment: You only ever store a single value in your 2d array, what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm tring to store the file name in one part and the md5 hash value in the second part. I am trying to loop through the second part and find duplicates, then I would display the duplicates with the file name from the first part of the array. Trying to just find duplicate files with the md5 value.

Comment: As @AlexeiLevenkov points out, your data structure makes little sense - if you want a structure that reprsents your stated goal, something like `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` makes more sense, where the key is the md5 as a string, and the value is a list of file names that hashed to that md5.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot - beat my answer by 16 seconds :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Preston and Alexei. I will look into that.

Comment: Make sure to dispose of the `MD5` objects you keep creating in each iteration of the loop. Either use a [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement or call `MD5.Dispose()` after you're done with the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you trying to get map of MD5 hash to list of files with that hash. It may be better to directly express that in data strucutre:

```
var hashToFiles = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

Now when processing new file you have `hash` + `fileName` - so you can check if it is already in the map and add new/update existing entry:

```
if (hashToFiles.ContainsKey(hash))
{ 
  // add new entry
  hashToFiles.Add(hash, new List<string>{fileName});
}
else
{
  hashToFiles[hash].Add(fileName);
}
```

So with map build the only thing left is to find items with more than one elements

```
var keyValueForDups = hashToFiles.Where(item => item.Value.Length > 1);
```

Notes:

- using SHA256 is better than outdated MD5, but ok for your purposes
- in your current code you are recreating array every time instead of using list and appending to it
- use custom class to hold `{hash, fileName}` pair to make code readable